# How to use jQuery's .css() with variable property name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Instead of writing:

```
$('div').css({'backgroundColor': 'red'});
```

I want to write something like:

```
$('div').css({get_property_name(): 'red'});
```

where `get_property_name()` will return `"backgroundColor"`, `"color"`, `"border-top-color"`, or any other property.

What options do I have to make it work ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The `.css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) can also be called as `.css(propertyName, value)`.

```
$('div').css(get_property_name(), 'red');
```

If you really need the dictionary representation:

```
var d = {};
d[get_property_name()] = 'red';
$('div').css(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign an object those values and pass it to `.css()`

```
var styles;
styles[get_property_name()] = 'red';
$(div).css(styles);
```